# Wordpress Some custom posts don't render with archive

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website that was about 5-6 custom post types. I have an archive.php and all the rest needed files. Most of them render good with my archive page but 2-3 render with my index.php.

**What I tried:**

I tried to make a page for each custom post, archive-{post-type} etc.. but that didn't work.

-

Does anyone have an idea about what might cause some of them to render good and only 2-3 to be problematic?

Answer (score 0):

**Go through the below following tips and snippet.**

1. Remove if spaces on the top of your custom post archive file.
2. Go to Settings > Permalinks, change it to something else temporarily, press save, change it back to the original setting, press save again.
3. The below code snippet in your theme function.php

   ```
   function get_custom_post_type_template($template) {
      global $post;

   if ($post->post_type == 'my_custom_post_type') {
       $template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/archive-my_custom_post_type.php';
   }
   return $template;
   }

    //add_filter( "single_template", "get_custom_post_type_template" );//for single page
     add_filter( "archive_template", "get_custom_post_type_template" ); //for archive
   ```

Comment: Thank you for you response @VijayaLakshmi, I'll try this out in a couple of hours, hopefully it will work. Thanks !